# Locating a Weatherstrip for door that is NOT foam and vinyl

Tags: weatherstripping, silicone, rubber

I have a standard Kerf weatherstrip for my door. Because it is made of vinyl and foam, my cat can shred it to pieces. 
Is there another type of weatherstrip (rubber, silicone, etc.) that will be more resistant to the cats clawing? I need a thicker size. I've checked out the bulb kerf weatherstrips but they only seem to get up to 1/2". I need about a 1" bulb. I've been looking online for hours now, and I'm hoping someone has a lead for me. Thanks! [image: this is the weatherstrip I'm using now]

Comment: This is more of a product recommendation and that is off topic. please revise or delete.

Comment: Class of product, not specific product.

Answer (score 3):

Metal weatherstrips used to be popular, and you can still find them, but there's a reason they fell out of fashion: they require very tight tolerances at the door/jamb interface, and even if you set them up perfectly, they still don't seal as well as soft weatherstrips. I'd look into alternate solutions, like installing a storm door outside the main one.

Answer (score 2):

There are felt weatherstrips, though I don't know that you'd find that shape in them - they are fairly durable.

There are "commercial" rubber weatherstrips, some of which are quite robust.

There are the "V-Seal" style strips which are a more robust plastic, no foam.

Comment: Ecnerwal,Do you know of a link/store where I could look for a "commercial" or "v-seal" weatherstrip?

Comment: Ecnerwal, Do you know of a link/store where I could look for "commercial" or "V-seal" weatherstrips? (not in bulk, just one door) I tried Home Depot with no luck. Thank you for your prompt response!